# Google Analytics API (v4)- how can can I get pagePath or the url in response ? Currently only getting pageTitle with pageviews

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm in process of migrating google analytics code from version 'v3' to 'v4', below is the JSON request query. I'm successfully getting page-title and page-views for the specified urls in the dimensionFilterClauses->expressions field, but I'm not getting the page-path/url.

In 'v3' for the exact same metrics and dimensions I was able to get page-title, page-path/url, and page-views.

Is there anything that I need to add in the below query so as to get the url info?

```
      [ "viewId" => $profileId,
        "dateRanges" => [
            "startDate" => $startDate,
            "endDate" => $endDate
        ],
        "metrics" => [
            "expression" => "ga:pageviews",
        ],
        "dimensions" => [
            "name" => "ga:pagePath",
            "name" => "ga:pageTitle"
        ],
        "dimensionFilterClauses" => [
            'filters' => [
                "dimensionName" => "ga:pagePath",

                "operator" => "IN_LIST",

                "expressions" => ["/one/path1",
                                  "/two/path2"]
            ]
        ],
        "orderBys" => [
                "fieldName" => "ga:pageviews",
                "sortOrder" => "DESCENDING"
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: I'm now getting pagePath, so instead of sending request in JSON version I modified  it and build the request in OOPs way and got the results that I expected. I still couldn't figure out the issue using above query structure. I also tried the tool 
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet 
 and got response what I wanted. So there's something that I'm missing with the above query.